# Log the status of the ADF (Azure Data Factory) pipeline run

Tags: azure-data-factory, kql, azure-log-analytics

I have an ADF Pipeline with a trigger that runs the pipeline once every day. I would like to find out the status of the pipeline run (latest pipeline run) and log it somewhere (maybe log analytics). How do I do that?

[image]

UPDATE:

I followed the solution suggested below however I don't see any logs on running the query ***ADFPipelineRun*** in log analytics. What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case if you want to have a log pertaining to only the recent run, then you would have to write a custom logic within your pipeline (like a script activity that would write in a database the status of the pipeline at the end)

sample reference which is my blog:
https://datasharkx.wordpress.com/2021/08/19/error-logging-and-the-art-of-avoiding-redundant-activities-in-azure-data-factory/

In case if you are comfortable querying a list of logs and filtering out the latest one based on some filter logics, then you can use log analytics or storage blob by enabling diagnostic settings

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Can you please clarify 2nd option? Should I add log analytics to the pipeline? Please clarify? Or should I update the setting of the pipeline to send logs to log analytics? Please clarify the steps required.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-configure-diagnostics this doc can help

Comment: I followed the solution suggested above however I don't see any logs on running the query ADFPipelineRun in log analytics. What am I missing?