# Arm template for Azure data factory with diagnostics settings in bicep

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep, azure-diagnostics

I have the following bicep to create ADF resource:

```
resource dataFactory 'Microsoft.DataFactory/factories@2018-06-01' = {
  name: name
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  properties: {
    globalParameters: {
      environment: {
        type: 'String'
        value: environmentAbbreviation
      }
    }
  }
  location: location
}
```

I need to add a diagnostic setting to ADF resource as follows:

[image]

How do I update the bicep?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create diagnostic settings in ADF using Bicep. Below is the code.

**Bicep code for creating data factory**

- This code is for creating data factory. It is same as the code in question.

```json
param settingName string='XXXXX'
param factoryName string='XXXXX'
resource datafactory 'Microsoft.DataFactory/factories@2018-06-01' = {
  name: factoryName
  location: resourceGroup().location
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  properties: {
  }
}
```

**Bicep code for adding diagnostic setting**

- In order to add diagnostic setting to data factory, below code is added along with the code to create data factory.

```json
resource factoryName_microsoft_insights_settingName 'Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/providers/diagnosticSettings@2017-05-01-preview' = {
  name: '${factoryName}/microsoft.insights/${settingName}'
  location: resourceGroup().location
  properties: {
    workspaceId: 'XXXX'
    logAnalyticsDestinationType: 'Dedicated'
    logs: [
      {
        category: 'PipelineRuns'
        enabled: true
        retentionPolicy: {
          enabled: false
          days: 0
        }
      }
      {
        category: 'TriggerRuns'
        enabled: true
        retentionPolicy: {
          enabled: false
          days: 0
        }
      }
      {
        category: 'ActivityRuns'
        enabled: true
        retentionPolicy: {
          enabled: false
          days: 0
        }
      }
    ]
    metrics: [
      {
        category: 'AllMetrics'
        timeGrain: 'PT1M'
        enabled: true
        retentionPolicy: {
          enabled: false
          days: 0
        }
      }
    ]
  }
  dependsOn: [
    datafactory
  ]
}
```

- When the above both codes are combined and run, resources got deployed successfully.
  [image]
- The above code will enable the categories - Pipeline runs log,Trigger runs log, Pipeline activity runs log. Change the code as per the requirement.
  [image]

**Reference:** [Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings - Bicep, ARM template & Terraform AzAPI reference | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.insights/diagnosticsettings?pivots=deployment-language-bicep)

Comment: Thank you! How do I set destination table to Azure Diagnostics?

Comment: If you want to archive in storage account, you need to use `storageAccountId: 'XXX'`  in properties. Refer the [link1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.insights/diagnosticsettings?pivots=deployment-language-bicep). This [link2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/resource-manager-diagnostic-settings?tabs=bicep#diagnostic-setting-for-azure-sql-database) has sample codes.

Comment: Sorry my question is logAnalyticsDestinationType: 'Dedicated' this sets to 'Resource Specific' how do I set it to 'Azure Diagnostics'?

Comment: Use  `logAnalyticsDestinationType: 'AzureDiagnostics'` instead of `logAnalyticsDestinationType: 'Dedicated'`

Comment: Thanks can you please answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75479291/log-the-status-of-the-adf-azure-data-factory-pipeline-run

Comment: It is answered already?

Comment: I tried the solution above. I keep getting error: The resource type '/' does not support diagnostic settings. I gave the workspaceId as resourceId('microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces',<Workspace ID>) what am I missing?

Comment: The full ARM resource ID of the Log Analytics workspace to which you would like to send Diagnostic Logs.

Comment: Example: /subscriptions/4b9e8510-67ab-4e9a-95a9-e2f1e570ea9c/resourceGroups/insights-integration/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/viruela2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252095/discussion-between-aswin-and-user989988).